# T-SQL : does this geographic distance algorithm fail to take curvature of earth into account

Tags: t-sql, geography

Does the following distance calculation fail to take into account the curvature of the earth?

> "The deviation of STDistance() on common earth models from the exact
>   geodesic distance is no more than .25%. "

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx

```
create proc findNearbyZips
@lat float,
@lon float,
@radius float
as
begin

declare @geo geography;
set @geo = geography::Point(@lat, @lon,4326);

with ZipsWithinRadius as
(
select zip5, city, state from zips
where
@geo.STDistance( zips.centroidGeoLocationInBinaryFormat ) <= @radius * 5280.00
)
select [...]


end
```

Comment: Your question phrasing suggests you think it *does* fail to take that into account. Why not give us some [**Expected Results** and (presumably different) **Actual Results**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000029.html) ?

Comment: Zipcodes that are 300 miles away are satisfying a 100 mile radius condition. E.g. Boston and Philadelphia.

Comment: What does the 5280 number mean? Also, check that you are using the correct units so you dont do calculations in miles when it should be kilometers or vice versa.

Comment: @Jakob you have it, I think. 5280 is the number of feet in a mile, but I'm pretty sure `STDistance` here wants metres.

Comment: Aha. Make it an answer Jakob and I'll accept it. Thanks for pointing out my dumb error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you use the correct units so you dont calculate things in miles when it should be meters or vice versa. When in doubt, assume SI base units (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit)